# cross compilation of a code

Tags: mips, cross-compiling

I am trying to cross compile some code. It has a directory structure. I compile it with non-recursive make using auto tools. It works fine. 
It has a hash implementation using glib2.0. When I try to cross compile it for mips64 (with flags CC=/path to sdk's gcc, --build=mips64, --host=i686 LD=/path to sdk's ld flags) architecture, it gives me an error that /usr/local/sdk/path to ld flags/ -lglib2.0 not found
Then i try to cross compile glib with some flags. IT gave me an error /usr/local/sdk/path to ld flags/ -lffi not found.
I downloaded lib ffi and cross compiled it. Again I came across errors but somehow managed to remove them. Then I moved to glib, and when compiled it, got an error stating
/usr/local/sdk/path to ld flags/ -ldl not found -lrt not found -lz not found

Please help. Whats the right way of cross compiling glib?

Comment: You should give more details. And you should obviously get or build (with a cross-compiler, etc.) all the libraries -even system ones like `-ldl` or `-lrt` or basic ones like `-lz` - needed for your target machine

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to build your own toolchain. Toolchain building is a black art best left to wizards. The rest of us generally download the  [Code Sourcery pre-built toolchains from Mentor Graphics](https://sourcery.mentor.com/sgpp/lite/mips/portal/release1798).

If you see yourself as an apprentice wizard, then try [this](http://cross-lfs.org/view/1.0.0/mips/).